# HP ML360 G6 server won't boot after swapping system disk

Tags: raid, hp, hp-proliant, hardware-raid, hp-smart-array

I am hoping for some help since I am completely out of ideas how to solve this!

I have a ML360 G6 server with a smartarray p410 controller.
All disks conifured in 4 separate arrays in raid 0 (I know, there is no redundancy in this setup, not is there any performace gain. In our environment, we need all diskspace available and can't afford to purchase more space, so please do spare me comment's like "you should consider purchasing...." or "you should consider rebuilding with mirroring" etc.

Disk 0 - System - 250 GB
Disk 1 - User files - 1 TB
Disk 3 - User Files - 1 TB
Disk 4 - Backup of all user files - 2 TB

A few weeks ago, I had no other choise but to tell my boss that we MUST change the system disk, since there was only 1 GB left available on the disk after cleaning out temp files etc. 
Unfortunately, I was not allowed to purchase a bigger disk. He pulled a 500 GB disk from another machine that he thought didn't need that disk and told me to clone and swap.

Fine, disk cloned... and swapped..  but...
SmartArray ofcourse tells me that disk0 has either failed or swapped for a spare, and gave me the option to either skip configuring and continue without logical drives, or to accept possible data loss and rebuild the array.

I let the system rebuild the array, and now it can't boot.
Before I do something stupid, I need some advice....

Is this because rebuilding the array is simply deleting the contents of the new disk? Or is there anything I have forgot?

If I, now that the new disk is built into the array, start the clone process again, by attaching the old disk to a USB cabinet and have it cloned that way, could that help me?

I hope you understand my problem and what I am asking for.
If not, don't hesitate to ask!

Thanks!

Comment: It seems as though you already passed that stage.

Comment: @KonradGajewski What stage? Your answer is not helping much...

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good place to be employed.

Comment: @ewwhite No, it isn't.. but it's better than not being employed at all....

Comment: @Rickard It's a comment, not an answer. The way you described it, it seems that you lost your data, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it after all.

Since I cloned the disk, I still had the original disk without any errors (except for the main reason for the swap, it was too small and needed a bigger disk), which meant I could just redo the clone process.

With the new disk added to the array, which whas then marked as fresh after array rebuild, I just attached the old disk via a USB cabinette, restarted the clone process and when done, removed the USB cabinette from the system and rebooted.

System is up and running!

I wish I had a boss who recognized the needs and could give me what I need in order to make a proper setup, however, I don't, so I have to do with what we got. Hence the horrible setup that we actually got.

I also wish, that people who comment when help and advice is asked for, gave usefull comments. "It seems as though you already passed that stage" does not help in any way, shape or form. Better refrain from those comments, they are not necessary and only adds to confusion and bad mood!

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution.